# WAMP Server doesn't redirect to my joomla projects

Tags: joomla, wamp

I have some Joomla websites on my Wamp, `WWW` folder, by opening localhost I can see, as usual, my projects, tools and alias, but always when I select one project it opens the browser to `http://mywebsite`, which does not work, instead of `localhost/mywebsite`, this is a simple problem that I can fix every time, but how to configure Wamp to do that automatically?

I am asking this because I think there is something that I don't understand, about the configuration or about the browser.

I am not sure if this is relevent, but it is currently listening on the `port:80`

Thank you in advance

Comment: I've always preferred using a VirtualHost for Wamp projects: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4156/virtual-host-for-joomla

Comment: Thank you @Lodder, unfortunately changing the host and Apache conf didnt work for me, I restarted, and the links are still dead.

Comment: Hmm odd, and I assume the Wamp icon in the taskbar is green, right? Also, are you using Windows 10?

Comment: Yes, actually it's green, and I am using Windows 7.